# Master-detail navigation in Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a master-detail page in blazor wasm: a left panel with a list of items, and a right panel with the selected item.

An example (ascii generated [here](https://asciiflow.com/#/share/eJyrVspLzE1VssorzcnRUcpJrEwtUrJSqo5RqohRsrI0M9GJUaoEsowsDIGsktSKEiAnRkkBAnwdg0NcgxRwABfXEEdPn5iYvEdT9gxdBHG%2FQmZJaq6CIYr%2FQMJEAoQ52CVpZA7Y0Ub4zKEQkezuR9Mmko%2FIsw8SCLS1g95%2Boq99dE4jkGRrjC5JujnYJQfMnIEJRxOK3Y1DcsDMGboI6H4gQvNXRklJQbGVvn55ebleakVibkFOql5yfq4%2BKPb0jWKUapVqAUgyQu8%3D)), with item 2 selected:

```
       MASTER                        DETAIL
+--------------------+----------------------------------------+
| item 1             |                                        |
|                    |                                        |
|                    |               item 2                   |
+--------------------+                                        |
|░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░|                                        |
|░item 2░░░░░░░░░░░░░|                                        |
|░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░|                                        |
|░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░|                                        |
+--------------------+                                        |
| item 3             |                                        |
|                    |                                        |
|                    |                                        |
+--------------------+                                        |
| item 4             |                                        |
|                    |                                        |
|                    |                                        |
+--------------------+----------------------------------------+
               https://www.example.com/items/2
```

URLs:

- `/items` for page showing items without a selection
- `/items/2` for page showing items with item 2 selected

I managed to do all that, using this approach:

- The page has a `<Master Selected=OnSelected />` component (left), and a `<Detail Id=_selectedId />` component (right)
- When an item is clicked in the master component (left), it raises an event with the `Id`
- The page handles that event (in `OnSelected(int id)`), and passes the id to the detail component (right)
- The detail component (right) shows the new item

I also want the browser's location updated from `/items` to `/items/2`, so I used: `NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/items/" + id)`. <strike>**But that reloads all components**.</strike>

Workarounds:

- I haven't found a way to update the browser location without reloading the page (though I could do that in javascript). Even if that were possible, I'm not sure that's a good way to do it.
- I could use a query string parameter instead, `/items?id=10`, then the `NavigationManager` would (I think) avoid the rerendering - but I can't use this approach, it must be part of the URI.

What is the recommended way to handle master-detail navigation in blazor?

#### UPDATE

The underlying error was actually unrelated to my design. So it actually **works**, and is a perfectly valid approach for master-detail navigation. But I recommend MrC's design in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use a Layout for this.

There are many ways to solve the problem. the level of complexity in the solution depends on the functionality required.

Here's a normal page version using weather forecasts that demonstrates one way.  Create a blank Layout if you want a vanilla look.

First my mods to the WeatherForecastService:

```cs
public class WeatherForecastService
{
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>? Forecasts { get; private set; }

    public WeatherForecast? Forecast { get; private set; }

    public async Task<bool> GetForecastsAsync()
    {
        if (this.Forecasts is null)
            this.Forecasts = await _getForecastAsync();

        return true;
    }

    public async Task GetForecastAsync(int id)
    {
        // mimic an async fetch
        await Task.Delay(100);
        this.Forecast = Forecasts?.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Id == id);
    }


    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

    private async Task<IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>> _getForecastAsync()
    {
        // mimic an async fetch
        await Task.Delay(100);
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Id = index,
            Date = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(index)),
            TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        });
    }
}
```

The Viewer component:

```cs
@inject WeatherForecastService ForecastService

@if (ForecastService.Forecast == null)
{
    <p><em>No Record Selected</em></p>
}
else
{
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">Date</div>
            <div class="col-6">@ForecastService.Forecast.Date</div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">Temperature &deg; C</div>
            <div class="col-6">@ForecastService.Forecast.TemperatureC</div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">Temperature &deg; F</div>
            <div class="col-6">@ForecastService.Forecast.TemperatureF</div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">Summary</div>
            <div class="col-6">@ForecastService.Forecast.Summary</div>
        </div>

    </div>
}

@code {
    [Parameter] public int? Id { get; set; }

    private int? currentId;

    protected async override Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        if (this.currentId != Id)
        {
            await ForecastService.GetForecastAsync(this.Id ?? 0);
            this.currentId = this.Id;
        }
    }
}
```

And the list component:

```cs
@inject WeatherForecastService ForecastService

@if (ForecastService.Forecasts == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <table class="table">
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var forecast in this.ForecastService.Forecasts)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="/fetchdata/@forecast.Id"> @forecast.Date.ToShortDateString()</a></td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}

@code {

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        => await ForecastService.GetForecastsAsync();
}
```

And then the new `FetchData`:

```cs
@page "/fetchdata/{Id:int}"
@page "/fetchdata"

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
            <WeatherList />
            </div>
        <div class="col-8">
            <WeatherViewer Id=this.Id />
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public int? Id { get; set; }
}
```

Note:

- All the data and data management resides in the service.
- There's no page reloading: just a parameter change.  As the navigation is to the same page we use `OnParametersSetAsync` in the viewer to check if we need to refresh the selected item.

[image]

Comment: Didn't see it was you asking the question.  I have an often quoted saying on here "Get your data out of your components".  It comes down to "Separation of Concerns".  There's a bit of a diatribe of mine here - https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.SeparationOfConcerns.

Comment: I've completely redesigned, thanks! It is now more robust, but the underlying problem still exists - both master and detail are rerendered on each click in the master. This is easily verified by logging in their initialise and dispose methods. For a small table this is fine, but with 1000s of rows, it slows down the UI perceptibly. I've skimmed the docs which mentioned data virtualisation - I'll look into that. But before I do, off the top of your head, *is the rerendering expected?* (I thought by loading the same page, blazor was smart enough to reuse the components.)

Comment: UPDATE: strange, I've created a barebones project with just your code, and also added logging in the components' init and dispose methods. The components seem to be created just once, as you said. So the problem must be elsewhere in my code, and your example was spot on!

Comment: I was just about to sit down and take a look.  Saved me the effort!  The key think to look out for is what I call "Render cascades" when an event (such as a button press or other UI event) cascades a render down the tree.  Any `ComponentBase` component with a reference `Parameter` will render (beware `ChildContent` is a `Renderfragment` is an object).

Comment: Found the problem: `App.razor` had `<Navigating>...</Navigating>` which I probably copied from the docs. It caused rerendering of all components. Once removed, everything worked. That means my design above was actually correct all along, and is a valid solution to "master-detail navigation in blazor" (having orchestration performed by the parent page or component). However, I prefer your approach (the work is perfomed in the data service itself) as it will scale better once the page and its components become more complicated. So cheers for all your help!

Comment: Improvement: I removed data loading (calls to `GetForecastsAsync` and `GetForecastAsync`) from the components, so they only react to changes (via the notification pattern). I then added those calls to the page, which calls them in `OnInitialized` and `OnParametersSet`, respectively. More centralised and easier to maintain.

Comment: NP - glad to help. I normally use centralised notification, but in this instance, you don't need it to solve the specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

I finally discovered the problem, and it was actually unrelated to my design. So it actually works, and is a perfectly valid approach for master-detail navigation.

To summarise:

- The page has a `<Master Selected=OnSelected />` component (left), and `<Detail Id=_selectedId />` component (right)
- When an item is clicked in the master component (left), it raises an event with the id
- The page handles that event (in `OnSelected(int id)`), and passes the id to the detail component (right)
- The detail component (right) shows the new item

So the "orchestration" between the two components is performed by the parent page (or component). It detects when an item was clicked in the master component, and updates the detail component.

**Note that I nonetheless recommend MrC's design in the accepted answer.** It shows how to perform this work indirectly, in the data service itself.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using NavigationManager, you should use an event callback from Master Component (Master.razor) to tell its parent Component (Mainlayout.razor) that the Id selected has changed. Thus now Mainlayout can pass the new Id into its second child Detail Component. The Detail Component then will rerender accordingly.

Further reference on event callback : https://www.pragimtech.com/blog/blazor/blazor-eventcallback/

To force the Detail component to be rerendered, you can also use
OnParameterSet on the Detail component.

Read more here :
[Executing method on Parameter change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54345380/executing-method-on-parameter-change)

Comment: Hi Fitri, and thanks! Yes, as explained above, that is exactly what I'm doing. The problem is that it won't update the URI, which is why I used the `NavigationManager`. But of course, it doesn't work as desired. I've updated the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. Sorry for not understanding it clearly. I have one question, how do you know that it actually does that reloads all components? Based on my reading from different questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71271942/blazor-update-state-in-url , they said apparently it will only trigger OnParameterSet only .

Comment: Because there is a flicker that shows that the components are being redrawn.

Comment: Update: turns out the problem was elsewhere, so your intuition about the problem was correct, and it should work as you expected. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach, where the URL does not show the id, e.g. `https://www.example.com/items`. (That's useful for a client-facing app where the ids are irrelevant, because they can't be shared or emailed as they're specific to one user.)

- start with the same design as that in the accepted answer
- in the page: remove `@page "/received/{Id:int}"` and remove everything to do with `Id`
- in the master component: change `<a>` to `<button @onclick=@(OnClick(forecast.Id))>` and in the `OnClick` event handler use `await ForecastService.GetForecastAsync(id)`
- in the detail component: remove `OnParametersSetAsync` and remove everything related to `Id`, and instead bind to `ForecastService.Forecast`